# Selenium C# 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' error

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I am trying to access a radio button. From my research I found the element using the name, since the elements of a radio button have the same name. I want to select the second button, but I get an element not visible exception and the location property of the element returned is outside the window. However, I can see the element on the page.

The exception: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> webElements = webElement.FindElements(By.Name("thename"));
webElements[1].SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

I tried to move to location using the execute javascript as well as the Actions method. Neither worked.

I tried all possible keys to send to click for the Actions method:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.MoveToElement(webElements[1]);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
actions.Click();
actions.Perform();
```

For the javascript executor I tried two methods. To scroll into view, and to scroll by the amount that the Location property of webElement[1] told me it was off by.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElements[1]);
string title1 = (string)js.ExecuteScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(557329,136);");
```

I still keep getting the location not visible exception.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but you are looking for a radio button... why are you sending the ENTER key instead of doing a `.Click()`? Are you sure that the radio button you are seeing on the page is actually the 2nd element with that name? It's possible there are some hidden elements with the same name. Try `webElements[1].GetAttribute("outerHTML");` and see if that returns the HTML of the tag you are looking for.

Comment: I would rather take a closer look into the `html`. I have previous experience with radio button being not legacy radio button actually. Can you share the html here if possible

Answer (score 0):

A quick check you could do is open the developer tools in browser and in the console see if document.querySelector("[name='thename']") finds the element. If not, maybe that element is in an iframe or the name you are using may have a typo. You will also want to make sure that the radio button you are trying to access is below 'webElement' in the DOM tree. It's also possible that the page is still loading when you are checking for the element. To check for this put in a wait before trying to find the element so the page can load fully.

Comment: You actually want `document.querySelectorAll("[name='thename']")[1]` because you want the 2nd element.